# java awt textfield update

Tags: java, user-interface, awt, repaint

I have an issue with my java application. I already read some questions here and none of them helped me. The issue is that I am trying to change text in my textbox which is defined this way:

```
public java.awt.TextField param1;
```

After that I want to load parametre from xml file (I am able to get parametre value), then set it in the textfield.

```
BP_evolution.gui.param1.setText(xsr.getText()); //xsr is XMLStreamReader
BP_evolution.gui.param1.repaint();
```

Where am I wrong with my code, please?

Thanks for the answer!
Martin

Comment: do you get null pointer exception ???

Comment: nope, application is running withou any errors/exceptions

Comment: Can you add more information to your question, e.g. what happens/ what happens not? It would also be helpful to know it `xsr.getText()` returns a non-empty string.

Comment: Program is still running (till I quit it myslef) and what does not happen is that text is not shown in the TextBox. Thats all my problem.. xsr.getText() returns correct string (output control).

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.